# Eclipse não para nos Breakpoints

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

Durante o desenvolvimento do código. O eclipse não realiza a parada nos breakpoints.

Após algumas pesquisas alterei a configuração do eclipse porém não acarretou nenhuma alteração do estado de eclipse.

Observação:

1. Estou suando o java 1.8
2. Eclipse ultima versão
3. Desenvolvimento JAVA

Comment: qual a versão do seu JDK?

Comment: Para qual linguagem?

Comment: Aviso do Google Tradutor: A sua pergunta é que o Eclipse não pára mais em pontos de interrupção como costumava ser quando você executa o modo de depuração e gostaria?

Comment: Coloque `System.out.println("aqui");` antes do _breakpoint_ para verificar se está realmente _"passando"_ onde deseja

Comment: Tenta assim, edita o arquivo eclipse.ini e coloca como primeiro parâmetro um -clean. Roda o eclipse de novo e avisa se funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apos pesquisas na internet, segui estes passos:

1. Project: Clean
2. Desabilitei Build Automatically

Reiniciei o servidor e tudo voltou ao normal